# Is it possible to increase the packet size while using tracert (for traceroute) in windows cmd?

Tags: cmd.exe, wireshark, sniffing, packet-loss

I am looking to increasing the packet size while using the `tracert` (traceroute) command in Windows CMD.
But in the windows options, it does not give an option for increasing the packet size and uses the default 64 bytes.

I am trying to see where the packet is being dropped in Wireshark when the packet size is too much so that the receiver drops it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The TRACERT diagnostic utility determines the route to a destination by sending
[Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol)
echo packets to the destination. Its parameters are well-known and packet size
is not one of them.

The packet size is determined by the ICMP protocol and cannot be
increased indefinitely.
The above Wikipedia link gives 255 as the maximum size.

You may of course create your own program as alternative to TRACERT and tack
rubbish bytes to the end of the packet, but you risk intermediate firewalls
rejecting this as an attack using malformed packets.

Perhaps you meant the `ping` utility, where the size can be modified using the
`-l` parameter, rather than `tracert`.

Comment: no I meant the tracert and not the ping utility. Because in Unix you can very well increase the packet data using the traceroute command (traceroute www.google.com 80). It is weird that windows does not have this option.

Comment: If you miss this option, you can easily find a Windows port of traceroute. Myself, I don't understand the need for it, and the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute) does say "The specified size can be ignored in some situations or increased up to a minimal value".

Comment: @harrymc: I don't know where you got the 255 from, but ICMP doesn't have any specific limitation on the total packet size – it can be as large as IP is able to carry, even beyond the link MTU (with the IP header specifying the payload size, just like with UDP). While there are restrictions on how much of the original packet can be included in an error reply, there aren't any restrictions on how large or small an Echo request can be – some `ping` tools send 32 bytes of payload, others send 64 bytes, and some indeed allow you to set whatever size you need.

Comment: As for the need, a common use is to check for issues related to MTU and to Path MTU Discovery, as the Linux `tracepath` tool does.

Comment: @user1686: Wikipedia didn't bother to go beyond 255 bytes for packet layout. So this is used as a timing test for larger packets?

Comment: Sometimes as a timing test, but more often as a test to see whether packets of a particular size can get through at all, and/or whether they correctly cause a "Fragmentation Needed" error to be sent back. (Especially non-TCP packets.) Both `tracepath` and `traceroute --mtu` on Linux try to do this, while for Windows I've only seen an old abandoned `mturoute` tool.

Comment: apparently, mturoute is not availabe in windows now. So I suppose I just have to use Linux for now? @user1686

Comment: You may always use WSL, which gives you a complete Linux.

Comment: I also noticed that Windows tracert does not have an option to use TCP for trace routing but linux has an option of -T. idk why but everyone suggests add ons for windows.

Comment: If Windows developers have not implemented this option, you must look at third-party products.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/ This came in handy to enable wsl and install the ubuntu command line. Thank you guys!